# Where can I find the key I discovered in the bathtub in the girl's bathroom?

Tags: silent-hill-origins

In Silent Hill Origins for the PSP, I got up to the part where you are in a hospital that the nice nurse was assigned to go have a meeting with a man (that you meet earlier in the game). I went to the girl's restroom, and I drained the water in the bathtub. Unfortunately, the key went down the drain with the water. Where do I go to obtain the key? And after I get the key, where do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the key in Otherworldly/Nightmare mode of the basement's East Pipe Room. In normal mode, it's blocked by a drain. The key opens the Archives Room on the second floor of the sanitarium.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information, please?  This seems to be lacking some context.

Comment: I answered my own question? I don't even remember answering this!